# How to create visible items for login users?

Tags: html, php

How can I create a menu for logged-in users?

I have this code for non-registered users:

```
    <form name="form1" style="float: left;" method="post" action="config.php">
        <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername">
        <input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

and for registered, logged-in users, this:

> You are now logged as: YouTOPname...

Comment: Why don't you use sessions in PHP? So then you can see if the user is logged in (session exists) or not :).

Comment: It looks like you need to read up more on Sessions in PHP. I take it that's the language you're using for this site?

Comment: `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['myusername'];`

Answer (score 0):

Use a session in PHP. Make sure to use `session_start()` at the top of your page otherwise sessions won't be recognised.

During the login process, create a session: `$_SESSION['user'] = true`

The code to decide which menu to display should look something like this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  //Menu for logged in member here
}
else {
  //Menu for logged out member here
}
```

Obviously there's other method for more dynamic web development, but this is the basic technique. Hope that helps :)

EDIT:
Don't forget to unset the session when logging out, otherwise the user menu will remain visible!